# Oracle Point Geometry: Find points in Table A which are not in Table B

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial, point

I have

- Table A (created with WITH and no spatial index) with point geometry: Point 1, Point 2, Point 3, Point 4 ....
- Table B with point geometry: Point A, Point B, Point C, ....
- Some points in Table A have the same geometry as some points in Table B. There is no other identical information like ID, Name, ...

The question is:

How to find all points in Table A which do NOT already exist in Table B?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` and, if they exist, `CREATE INDEX`) statements for your two tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data; **your** attempt at solving the problem; the issues and/or errors with **your** solution; and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the structure of your tables.

If you have two tables with the same number of columns you can do:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE_A
MINUS
SELECT col3, col4 FROM TABLE_B;
```

It doesn't matter if the column has the same name, but you need to give same datatype.
In addition col1 compares with col3, and col2 with col4.

If you have the real structure, share it please.